# How to get externally defined bean in java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a java config class that imports xml files with the @ImportResources annotation. In the java config I'd like to reference to beans that are defined in the xml config, e.g. like:

```java
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:WEB-INF/somebeans.xml"
    }
)
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setFoo(foo); // foo is defined in somebeans.xml
        return bar;
    }
}
```

I'd like to set the bean foo that has been defined in somebeans.xml to the bar bean that will be created in the java config class. How do I get the foo bean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either add a field in your configuration class and annotate it with `@Autowired` or add `@Autowired` to the method and pass in an argument of the type.

```
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
      Bar bar = new Bar();
      bar.setFoo(foo); // foo is defined in somebeans.xml
      return bar;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public Bar bar(Foo foo) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setFoo(foo); // foo is defined in somebeans.xml
        return bar;
    }
}
```

This is all explained in [the reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-using-import).

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. The essential sentence of the docs: "Remember that \@Configuration classes are ultimately just another bean in the container - this means that they can take advantage of \@Autowired injection metadata just like any other bean!"