# How to use the channel in Spring Integration but Using just java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

I have been reading the Spring Documentation and forums on Internet. I did something very similar to this: [sftp with java config in spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_19)

> The point is I would like to use the channel to send a message, So
>   I've created a method like this one
>
> ```
> private void MethodToSendMessageUsingSftp(MessageChannel channel, File file){
>         final Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
>         channel.send(message);
> }
> ```

But I don't know how to get the channel in order to set it into the MethodToSendMessageUsingSftp method, and send the message.

By the way, I'm doing all these things just because I'm changing some stuff from xml to java config in my projects:

So, my old project looks like this:

```
<bean id="uploadToSftpTasklet" class="someClass" scope="step">
    <property name="sftpChannel" ref="sftpChannel"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
                                   channel="sftpChannel"
                                   session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                   remote-directory-expression="whatever"
                                   charset="UTF-8"
                                   auto-create-directory="true"
                                   use-temporary-file-name="false"
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

If you see, in my `uploadToSftpTasklet` I'm referencing to the `sftpChannel`, and that is what I want to do using java config.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: that method is a part of some service in your application, managed bean. So, you can just `@Autowired` that channel into this service and go with the logic.

Although, to be honest, your question isn't clear. Everything in Spring Integration is a bean and fully based on the Spring Framework. So, dependency injection rules and all the configuration tricks are applied here as well.

Comment: I think you are right and I was confused by the example that I saw in the documentation.

I've updated the description if you want to see again.

Probably this is what you are saying that I have to do:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18696933/6243160